# Keep running an app in lock screen

Tags: 14.04, lock-screen

I am new at Ubuntu, and I have an app running with tomcat, to broadcast images.

I need this app keep running even if I lock th system (ctrl+alt+l).

Is there any way to do it?
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

Locking the system does not affect running processes if they expect any interaction.

Comment: Ok, but the app is like a screensaver, it shows images on a secondary display. When I lock Ubuntu, the app minimize and only appears the lock screen. It's possible to keep showing the app in the secondary screen, and the lock screen in the main display?